# How can I sum the data-attributes of some div boxes?

Tags: jquery, calculator

https://jsfiddle.net/ohoxjc40/

```
<div class="total" data-price="100"></div>
<div class="total" data-price="200"></div>
<div class="sum_total"></div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
       var total = 0;
        $(".total").each(function (i, price) {
            var price = $(this).data('price')
            total = total + parseInt(price);
            $('.sum_total').text(total);
      });
});
```

I want to calculate the data-attributes of my div boxes, but I cannot get any result.

Comment: Add Jquery to jsfiddle and script is working without problems.

Comment: I works fine for me if i add jquery to the fiddle

Comment: You need to include jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/ohoxjc40/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfect, but you forget to include the jquery library in the fiddle code. I have include it and it is showing the result.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       var total = 0;
        $(".total").each(function (i, price) {
            var price = $(this).data('price')
            total = total + parseInt(price);
            $('.sum_total').text(total);
      });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohoxjc40/1/)

Comment: Oh :) How could I forget that!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the fiddle. You need to import jQuery in your page to work with it and it is fine.